# cosmos show windows form on console screen in C#

Tags: c#, forms, console, window, cosmos

In cosmos, is there any way that I can show a window form on the console screen? If this is possible, will you please show me how to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

WinForms in Cosmos is definitely not possible even in the latest devkit. You'd need to code a VGA/VBE driver yourself, plug System.Drawing, and plug WinForms' backend to work with your driver and the rest of Cosmos.

Even then, displaying forms would be pretty slow, and you wouldn't have breathing room because VGA doesn't support anything above 640x480 as I recall (in cosmos that is), and VBE, 1280x1024 is the max IIRC.

In a while when graphics mature a bit more and work a lot more like FAT (create the driver then register it with a manager), I'll definitely port either WinForms or GTK# over.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your console i think you can't. But you can open a form.

**References/Assemblies/Framework find System.Windows.Forms**

add to **namespace**:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

and

```
Application.Run(new Form());
```

Comment: thanks for your help and were would I put Application.Run(new Form());

Answer (score 0):

In Cosmos OS you can't open Windows forms because the Cosmos OS doesn't have the Windows API in the Operating System.